# How can I see when data string is saved and shown like '??????'(UTF8)

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Hi I am trying to learn SQL and I created table using

```
pymysql = (..., charset='utf8')
```

and I inserted information to the table successfully but the data was shown like '???'
So I tried a couple of codes to set my databases to UTF8 googling stackoverflow answers
but still when I execute it, the table info shows '????'

Is there anything I might have missed? Thank you for your help in advance.

- I've just added the following command result whenever I save my info to the table; 
  /workspace/pythoninitiative/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xEC\x84\x
  9C\xEC\x9A\xB8...' for column 'location_name' at row 1")

Comment: What is the table definition `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`? What MySQL version? What pymysql version? What SQL is running that generates this error?

Comment: Thank you @danblack for your help! 1> I used "CREATE TABLE "~~" 2> mysql version is Ver 14.14 (Distrib 5.5.62, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3) 3>PyMySQL version is 0.9.3 4> I could see this table data by using "select * from ~~ query